# Problem rendering SVGs on safari with html5

Tags: html, svg

I'll admit right off the bat i'm very new to SVG graphics in html. That said i'm attempting to upgrade my site images to SVG's where appropriate.

I started with this code:

```
<svg class="logo">
    <image
      class="logo"
      xlink:href="https://cdn.badmonsterarts.com/main_logo.svg"
      src="https://cdn.badmonsterarts.com/main_logo.png"
    />
</svg>
```

Which works fine in chrome and firefox, however when tested on Safari(Both mobile and desktop) it rendered as a blank rectangle. That said I did some research and tried some stack overflow answers which brings us to my current code:

```
<svg
  class="logo"
  viewBox="0 0 256 75"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  role="img"
>
        <image
          class="logo"
          xlink:href="https://cdn.badmonsterarts.com/main_logo.svg"
          src="https://cdn.badmonsterarts.com/main_logo.png"
        />
</svg>
```

The problem however is this still works in chrome and firefox, but I still can't get it to render in Safari.

Here's the CSS i'm using to size it, logo wrapper is a div surrounding the SVG as a warpper:

```
.logo-wrapper {
  width: 256px;
  height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;

  .logo {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

I've also tried using `<use ... />` instead of `<image ... />` with no luck either, when I used `<use ... />` it didn't even render in chrome. I'm hoping one of your brilliant minds can lead me in the right direction and save my sanity.

If it helps anyone debug this, there's a link to the site that the SVG is being used on(The logo in the top left on the nav bar). 
https://www.badmonsterarts.com/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the image width and height to 100% of the viewBox it ought to work (I took the viewBox values from the external SVG).

By only setting the viewBox you make the SVG responsive – why you can leave out the `logo` class

```css
.logo-wrapper {
  width: 256px;
  height: 75px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-wrapper">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 679 200">
    <image width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://cdn.badmonsterarts.com/main_logo.svg" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would the viewbox be that big if the image is only rendered to 256x75?

Comment: Okay I just tried this, and it draws correctly and fixes safari, what am I missing here? I don't understand why this works but mine didn't?

Comment: Think of viewBox as the internal coordinate system of the SVG – a bit like how you would think of retina screens vs. old 1x screens – the screens are the same size but the retina screen has more available pixels for precision.

Comment: Chrome and firefox use 100% width and height as defaults – Safari and IE use 0... why the image is considered without size. By adding 100% Safari sizes the image to the viewBox – and it becomes visible

Comment: I hope it makes sense – SVG's are awesome but takes a lot of getting used to :-)

Comment: PS. here is a great read about the coordinate system: https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/

Comment: Thanks very much, you've been a huge help!